# create and insert a file in mysql database using java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'd like to create and insert my file (just .txt  file) into `MySQL` database at the same time using `hibernate`, I'm stuck at the part of inserting it :

here's the part that creates the file  :

```
BufferedWriter out = null;
        try  
        {
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out"+new Date().getHours()+""+new Date().getMinutes()+""+new Date().getSeconds()+".txt", true); 
            out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

            out.write("======== Date: "+new Date() +" ========");
            out.write("\n==================================================");
            out.write("\n===============Construction of file ==============");
            out.write("\n==================================================");
           //out.write( ... 
          //.... other lines      
        } 
        finally {
            out.write("\n=================================================");
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
         {

        System.out.println("ERROR");
                }
         finally {
            if(out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }

//.....
```

my Class  :

```
public class A   {

private Long AId;
private byte[] AFile;
//.. getters and setters 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to first map the variable with the column in the database
e.g.

```
@Column(name="column name in the database")
@Lob(type = LobType.BLOB)
private byte[] AFile;
```

Then you can use normal criteria query to insert the data.

Read the file and put into AFile
e.g.

```
IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input)
```

save to the database
e.g.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
//Add new Employee object
A a = new A();
a.setAFile("your byte array")

//Save the employee in database
session.save(a);

//Commit the transaction
session.getTransaction().commit();
HibernateUtil.shutdown();
```

Comment: then you can directly save the object to the database. :) what is the error you are getting?

Comment: i have updated the answer.. i hope you will get what you need. :) happy coding.

Comment: if possible accept the answer. if you got the solution. :)